# File command returns different results since upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Ubuntu 14.04 ships with file command v5.14.

When I use it on a JPG image file it returns `data`.

With Ubuntu 12.04 (file v5.09), it used to return `JPEG image data`...

What is the best solution to keep the same behavior? I tried using the `magic.mgc` file shipped with Ubuntu 12.04 but it is not compatible anymore with file v5.14.

Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am also getting a warning message with file 5.14:

`` /etc/magic, 4: Warning: using regular magic file `/usr/share/misc/magic' ``

Comment: I get the correct behavior, try reinstalling `sudo apt-get install --reinstall file` or maybe consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Have you verified this using both versions of `file` on the same file? Is this reproducible?

Comment: I tried reinstalling with no luck... It is very reproducible! I tried with this image for instance: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps not so much of an answer but I wanted to let you know how it looks on my system I'm using (14.04):

```
% file -v
file-5.14
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic
```

The only source of the magic :) is the file in /etc on my system since the other one is an empty directory:

```
% find /usr/share/misc/magic/
/usr/share/misc/magic/

% md5sum /etc/magic
272913026300e7ae9b5e2d51f138e674  /etc/magic

% ls -alh /etc/magic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 111 Apr  3  2014 /etc/magic
```

and it returns the following for many of the JPEGs I have:

```
% file *jpg
1Ns3345.jpg:      JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
anfffffggsel.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
1m32ssQ.jpg:      JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
fCWwevC.jpg:      JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
SCN_0001.jpg:     JPEG image data, EXIF standard
SCN_0002.jpg:     JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
SCN_0011.jpg:     JPEG image data, EXIF standard
SCN_0012.jpg:     JPEG image data, EXIF standard
for7sfe.jpg:      JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

It looks like my magic is better than yours :D

Comment: It's really weird cause I have the exact same magic file. Could you try with this image for instance: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg ?

Comment: @Such Hmmm, looks like `/etc/magic` is from [`libmagic1`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=etc%2Fmagic), perhaps reinstalling it might help.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I used to have another magic file /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc. Maybe it corrupted the installation of libmagic1 when upgrading to 14.04...